# Firebase React Js receiving duplicate pushes at a same time

Tags: reactjs, firebase

When I send push to someone from console or api, they are receiving duplicate pushes at a same time

```js
messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
  console.log(
    "[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ",
    payload
  );
  const notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.data.body,
    tag: "myapp",
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```

Comment: Where is this code located?

Comment: public folder `firebase-messaging-sw.js`